# Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Exception: No such entity with cartId = 1829505

Tags: magento2, cart, exception

I'm getting this error constantly every 10 seconds on my website. It apparently causes my website to crash sometimes. Below is an example of one of the error messages. Does anyone know what to do to fix this issue?

```
[2017-04-01 05:07:35] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Exception: No such entity with cartId = 1829505 in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/ooples.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array)
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array)
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php(36): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array)
#3 /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(655): Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array)
#4 /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(1757): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Array)
#5 /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(1877): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->_afterLoad(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#6 /vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/AfterEntityLoad.php(33): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->afterLoad(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#7 /vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntityLoad->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#8 /vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntityLoad), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#10 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#11 /vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault\Interceptor->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#12 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#13 /vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(51): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#14 vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read.php(124): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'load_after', Array)
#15 /vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(61): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 743, Array)
#16 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(655): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->load(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 743)
#17 /vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(531): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->load(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 743, NULL)
#18 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->load(743)
#19 /var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Interceptor.php(2314): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins('load', Array, Array)
#20 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php(241): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->load(743)
#21 /var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Api/ProductRepositoryInterface/Proxy.php(111): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository->getById(743, false, '1', false)
#22 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product.php(417): Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface\Proxy->getById(743, false, '1')
#23 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(212): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product->initProduct(743, Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#24 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product/View.php(109): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View->prepareAndRender(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), 743, Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#25 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View->execute()
#26 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#28 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#29 /vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#32 /vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#35 /vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#38 /vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#41 /vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Product/View/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#44 /vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#47 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#48 /vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#51 /vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#52 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#53 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'searchautocompl...')
#54 /vendor/mirasvit/module-search-autocomplete/src/SearchAutocomplete/Model/App/FrontController/Plugin.php(130): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#55 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Mirasvit\SearchAutocomplete\Model\App\FrontController\Plugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#56 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#57 /vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#58 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#59 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#60 /vendor/mirasvit/module-seo/src/Seo/Plugin/Event/BuiltinPlugin.php(109): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#61 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Mirasvit\Seo\Plugin\Event\BuiltinPlugin->aroundAroundDispatch(Object(Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#62 /var/generation/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callPlugins('aroundDispatch', Array, Array)
#63 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#64 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#65 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#66 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#67 /index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#68 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running as a Multi-Store, and/or taking orders through the Admin sometimes? Also what specific version of 2.x.x are you on?

You've most likely having a known open issue:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6522

> I'm having this issue on and off for the last couple of days.
>
> After downloading an updated database from our staging server, when I
>   try to checkout I was getting error message "No such entity with
>   cartId = 0".
>
> However, if I switch to a new incognito browser I was able to
>   checkout, while still getting the error in my regular browser.
>
> The issue seems to have something to do with the wrong ID getting
>   posting to estimate-shipping-methods rest api.
>
> Error in regular browser posting
>   /rest/default/V1/guest-carts/582/estimate-shipping-methods
>
> Incognito browser posting
>   rest/default/V1/guest-carts/8c5a23bf5bfb3040cce9c340af04b973/estimate-shipping-methods
>
> Which causes the function below to return zero because 582 is not a
>   valid mask_id.
>
> Magento version 2.1.3
>
> vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/GuestCart/GuestShippingMethodManagement.php
>
> ```
> public function estimateByExtendedAddress($cartId, AddressInterface $address)
> {
>     /** @var $quoteIdMask QuoteIdMask */
>     $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartId, 'masked_id');
>
>     return $this->getShipmentEstimationManagement()
>         ->estimateByExtendedAddress((int) $quoteIdMask->getQuoteId(), $address);
> }
> ```

Also, side note, sometimes its best to redact full paths from logs when posting to prevent people from having insight into the full file tree.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I made the same mistake without thinking. :)